# Laravel on shared hosting, post request doesn't work

Tags: angular, laravel

Hi I need some help on installing my laravel project on a shared hosting. I've tried these :

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-move-laravel-54-application-to-shared-hosting

https://laravel-news.com/subfolder-install

My folder structure is :

laravel/ web/

Where web/ has the contents of my /public/ laravel folder and of course the rest of my laravel project is in the laravel/ folder

Now it does work .. ish .. When I open my public url in my browser, the page is showing. But I also have a backend cms (Angular) project in my web/ folder. When I do a post from my Angular project to Laravel I see something very strange in my browser console.

I see the post request begin moved : [HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 17ms] and it gets converted to a GET request. And my route doesn't have that defined so I get an error back.

What can cause this behaviour?

Comment: What web server that you use? Apache or nginx? Another thing to check, Is your server setup do redirection for non http request?

Comment: It's Apache. 

"Is your server setup do redirection for non http request?" 

hmm don't know how to answer that. Is there a way to check that?

Comment: Try access your url with `http`. Example: `http://someawesomeapp.dev/web`. If it redirected to https. Make sure your Angular request is calling `https`

Comment: And also can you add the detail server response shown in the browser console/dev-tools?

Comment: Ah . no at the moment I'm using http .. and it's not redirected to https according to my browser console.

Comment: POST request : http://test.mysite.nl/mycms/website/page/add/
[HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 17ms]

Statuscode: 301

Response headers
Connection  :Keep-Alive
Content-Length : 358
Content-Type : text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date  :Mon, 30 Jul 2018 10:29:18 GMT
Keep-Alive : timeout=5, max=100
Location : http://test.mysite.nl/mycms/website/page/add/
Server : Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)


And right after I see a

GET request : http://test.mysite.nl/mycms/website/page/add/
Statuscode: 200

Comment: Is it work on your local? Since maybe the problem is in your Laravel handling the request. Redirection can caused by form validation or your controller returning redirection.

Comment: yes .. it does works local :( .. but then again .. on my local machine I use the artisan serve. 

Just something that popped into mind .. it's doing XHR request .. but my "api" routes are in web.php. So I'm going to move them to the api.php routes

Comment: So yeah fixed it https://medium.com/@mshanak/laravel-return-empty-response-690f8a308d9a Problem 1 ...